# Jetpack Compose LazyVerticalGrid items having a different size

Tags: android, gridview, android-jetpack-compose

When I'm trying to use LazyVerticalGrid to display a list of images, some grid items have a different size even the images itself have exactly same size 240x178.

I tied to use `modifier.fillMaxWidth()`, `modifier.matchParentSize()`, `modifier.fillMaxHeight()`, `modifier.fillMaxWidth()`, `modifier.fillParentMaxHeight()`, `modifier.fillParentMaxWidth()`, `modifier.requiredHeight(imageHeight)`, `modifier.requiredWidth(imageWidth)` but nothing had helped me to make images fill all available space without leaving any empty spaces between and some images continue to be not the same size with the others.

[image: current grig display]

Below is my current implementation and I'm using Coil for image loading if its important

```
 @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun TreasureGrid(treasures: List<MapTreasure>) {
        val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

        val imageWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp / 4
        val imageHeight = (imageWidth.times(1.348f))
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            cells = GridCells.Adaptive(imageWidth)
        ) {
            items(treasures.size) {
                TreasureItem(
                    treasures[it],
                    Modifier.requiredHeight(imageHeight).requiredWidth(imageWidth)
                )
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun TreasureItem(mapTreasure: MapTreasure, modifier: Modifier) {
        val resId = TMApplication.instance.resources.getIdentifier(
            mapTreasure.image,
            "drawable",
            TMApplication.instance.packageName
        )
        val matrix = ColorMatrix()
        val isOpened = getUser()?.openedTreasures?.contains(mapTreasure.name) == true
        if (isOpened.not()) {
            matrix.setToSaturation(0F)
        }
        Box {
            AsyncImage(
                model = resId,
                contentDescription = mapTreasure.description,
                modifier = modifier.clickable {
                    if (isOpened) {
                        activity?.let { DialogUtils.showTreasureInfoDialog(it, mapTreasure) }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Treasure not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }.matchParentSize(),
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(matrix)
            )
            val alpha = if (isOpened) 0f else 1f
            AsyncImage(
                model = R.drawable.treasure_key,
                contentDescription = mapTreasure.description,
                modifier = modifier.rotate(90f).scale(0.3f).alpha(alpha)
            )
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to make every grid item same size and remove the padding around it are highly appreciated

Comment: If even `requiredHeight` didn't helped you, maybe the problem is in images? Try setting `contentScale = ContentScale.Crop` for your `AsyncImage` big

Comment: @PylypDukhov thank you for your suggestion. Sadly, but `contentScale = ContentScale.Crop` and other scale types did not have any effect on the items size display in my case.

Comment: Can you try border modifier in your AsyncImage and describe what you see. Problem is in your images or row? Maybe you can try different compose version, could it be a bug?

Comment: @commandiron thank you for your comment. After checking with the border modifier I got the idea of what was wrong. The problem was not related to the code. I found out that the designer gave me images of the same size but with different paddings on each image, so the problem was in the image resource itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not related to the code. I found out that the designer gave me images of the same size but with different paddings on each image, so the problem was in the image resource itself.